# Pros and cons of fstream::open() v.s. fcntl::open()?

Tags: c++, linux, file, fstream, fcntl

As the title indicated, what's the difference between and advantages/disadvantages of open() from fstream library and linux fcntl library?

Comment: You mean apart from the fact that one is standard C++ so its use is consistent between systems, and the other is specific to linux?

Comment: I'm programing some hardware with a linux computer. I'm not sure which library is better for me to use. If the standard C++ library is consistent between systems, why Linux has its own "fcntl.h" library? What's the point of that?

Comment: The point is that not everybody uses C++. Are you seriously asking why life gives us choices? ^_^

Comment: First thing's first: there's no such thing as `fcntl::open()`.

Comment: There is no standard "one size fits all" operating system, or an API for one.  All operating systems provide services and functionality that are specific to themselves.  Which means you can do more on that system, but it won't work the same on another system.   In worst cases, system specific code is also more prone to failing, if the OS is updated or patched.  Conversely, standard techniques (like `fstream`) work reliably between systems (as long as you avoid undefined/unspecified/etc behaviour) but doesn't provide access to funky capabilities that are specific to a given OS.

Comment: @Peter Thanks, that helps.

Comment: @BoundaryImposition Thanks for the reply :)